# How do I submit a MVC view on load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, form-submit

I have a view that has a form with a single hidden submit button.  I want to submit the form when the page loads.  However, any submit I do in Javascript gives me this error:

> Unable to get property 'submit' of undefined or null reference

Here is my code:

PrintApplication.cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PrintApplications", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "PrintApplications", @class = "form-horizontal ", @commandname = "ModelContract", @target = "_blank" }))
    {
      <input id="btnPrintApplications" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="PrintApplications" name="submit" style="visibility: hidden" />
    }

<script>

    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.form.submit();
    }

</script>
```

In place of document.form.submit, I've also tried

```
var form = document.getElementById("PrintApplications");
form.submit();

document.forms["PrintApplications"].submit();

this.form.submit();
```

and other variations (with # in front of the form name, for example)

What is wrong with my code.  Is there any other way to submit the page automatically (without the user clicking any buttons)?

Edit: Here's my original code.  It didn't work in IE which is what set off the problem I'm having.  There was no error, but the form didn't submit.  This worked fine in Chrome though.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnPrintApplications").click();
    });
```

Edit 2: Here's the code I got to work using the code in the post from @barry

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrintApplications", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "PrintApplications", @class = "form-horizontal ", @commandname = "ModelContract", @target = "_blank" }))
{
    @*<input id="btnPrintApplications" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="PrintApplications" name="submit" style="visibility: hidden" />*@
    <div>
        If applications do not appear in a separate tab or window, please click the button below.
    </div>
    <input id="btnPrintApplications" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print Applications" name="print" />
}

<script>
  mySubmitButton = document.getElementById("btnPrintApplications");
    mySubmitButton.click();
</script>
```

Edit 3: Here's the code using the example from @chris-pratt.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrintApplications", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "PrintApplications", @class = "form-horizontal ", @commandname = "ModelContract", @target = "_blank" }))
{
    <div>
        If applications do not appear in a separate tab or window, please click the button below.
    </div>
    <input id="btnPrintApplications" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print Applications" name="print" />
}

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.forms['PrintApplications'].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like `document.onload`? While they *should* be functionally equivalent for the most part, `readystatechange` fires whenever there's some change in the document's "readiness", whatever that means, while `load` explicitly fires only when the element and all dependents have fully loaded.

Comment: Actually, try naming your submit button something other than "submit". MDN seems to imply it might be problematic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Thanks @chris-pratt for the feedback.  Just tried document.onload and renaming the input button "print" instead of submit.  Neither worked, but I didn't get an error this time.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplistic HTML document functions exactly as you want:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="Test" action="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value="test" />
    </form>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.forms['Test'].submit();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I originally used `document.onreadystatechange`, which also worked, but noticed IE 11 apparently fires that event twice, resulting in two popups. Regardless. Perhaps by working backwards you can find your problem.

Comment: Thanks @chris-pratt.  This worked as well.  I actually thought I tried the window.onload, so I was skeptical of trying this again, but I must have got some of the syntax wrong because your example worked.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

try thisway

```
mySubmitButton = document.getElementById("PerfSubmit");         
mySubmitButton.click();
```

with below code the form will get submitted

```
$('form')[0].submit();
```

or

```
mySubmitButton.trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thanks @barry.  This worked great.  I added the exact code using this approach to my original post.